# .HTACCESS and Redirecting

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, png

I've got this .htaccess file which redirects .PNG's to .PHP files (for dynamic image), however, I don't want to do that with all the .PNG's in the folder, as when I want to place a normal static image on my page, I can't, as it will will create a dynamic image.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z\0-9\s]+)\.png image.php?name=$1
```

I'm not very experienced with .HTACCESS, so any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How will the server know if you want it forwarded or not?  What will be the difference in the PNG's filename?

Comment: can you not add another rule to redirect .pngx to .png and then save your static files as a pngx?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed I was thinking whether I could get the dynamic images from another directory?

Comment: If they're in another directory, just put the .htaccess file in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `RewriteCond` which skips the following `RewriteRule` if a file `!-f` or directory `!-d` exists. I've included both for your reference - you might only want to use the `!-f` one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z\0-9\s]+)\.png image.php?name=$1 [L]
```

An example where this would be useful is if you have a php script which creates thumbnail images.
Point your html page at where the thumbnail .png *should* exist, and when it doesn't, redirect to a .php page which creates it, then both writes it to disk and serves it directly. The next request will hit the `RewriteCond` and find a matching thumbnail and serve it directly, bypassing the rewrite.

Comment: I added the [L] flag on the end to make it the Last rule to stop additional rewrites further down, if any.